# How to hide the address balloon in the Google Maps embedded iframe?

Tags: google-maps

I need to place a Google Maps embed map in a website. I setup the map on Google Maps website, copied the given `<iframe>` embed code and put it in my page.

The space for the map it's very limited, so I want to hide the address balloon from it, but leaving the red placeholder. I mean the huge white balloon with the place address in the center of the map. 
You can see it **[here](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=via+Zuccardi+8%2FA,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia,+Reggio+Emilia&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Via+Zuccardi,+8,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia+Reggio+nell%27Emilia,+Emilia+Romagna,+Italy&t=m&vpsrc=6&ll=44.851366,10.786772&spn=0.029207,0.054932&z=14&output=embed)**. This is the exact URL used in my `<iframe src>`.

I've tried to click the *Customize and preview embedded map* link under the given code, but I see no options to remove the balloon. If I remove in from the map preview, the code is not updated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution myself. A special parameter value is needed in the map URL:

```
&iwloc=near
```

Result **[here](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=via+Zuccardi+8%2FA,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia,+Reggio+Emilia&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Via+Zuccardi,+8,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia+Reggio+nell%27Emilia,+Emilia+Romagna,+Italy&t=m&vpsrc=6&ll=44.851366,10.786772&spn=0.029207,0.054932&z=14&output=embed&iwloc=near)**.

Comment: @DominicB-c At the end if the Maps URL. [**This**](http://is.gd/kCXgxC) is the `<iframe src>` attribute that Maps gives you, and [**this**](http://is.gd/sX39Kr) is the same with `&iwloc=near` appended at the end.

Answer (score 1):

just add 
 `&iwloc=1` 
in iframe src

Answer (score 1):

The 'iwloc' trick didn't work for me. It works when you use coordinates instead of the business name, as of 1/22/2018

1. Go to [Maps Ie](https://www.maps.ie/coordinates.html) to get your Coordinates
2. Go to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) and enter those coordinates (comma separated like this: 33.319663, -111.89780100000002)
3. Click on Share (located on the left)
4. Click on Embed Map
5. Configure the size of map that you want
6. Copy the  html

Resulting html is something like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3333.967410377096!2d-111.89998968453055!3d33.31966746342457!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzPCsDE5JzEwLjgiTiAxMTHCsDUzJzUyLjEiVw!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1516690469899" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image: Size configuration screen]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can edit it a lot more than what give on the customise page.

Exactly what do you mean by the "Address Balloon"?

When I see an embedded google map, I see a movement section at the top left, a type-of-map section at the top right, and a footer at the bottom of the map.
Is it any of these?

--UPDATE--
Try this

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=campagnola+emilia&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;hq=campagnola+emilia&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;ll=44.841266,10.759212&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=campagnola+emilia&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;hq=campagnola+emilia&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;ll=44.841266,10.759212&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: No, I mean the huge white balloon with the place address in the center of the map. You can see it here: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=via+Zuccardi+8%2FA,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia,+Reggio+Emilia&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Via+Zuccardi,+8,+42012+Campagnola+Emilia+Reggio+nell%27Emilia,+Emilia+Romagna,+Italy&t=m&vpsrc=6&ll=44.851366,10.786772&spn=0.029207,0.054932&z=14&output=embed. This is the URL used in my `<iframe src>`.

Comment: Ah ok. I should be able to manage this for you, but I have to go now :( Maybe tommorow.